# Get specific string out of array (Gravatar)

Tags: php, arrays, get, specifications, gravatar

I was wondering on how to get a specific string out of an array within this document:
https://gravatar.com/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50.php

I was working with the example given on the Gravatar page and started to get used to the following line:

```
$profile['entry'][0]['preferredUsername'];
```

The complete document (of mine) now looks like this so far:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE);

    $str = file_get_contents('https://www.gravatar.com/'.$_GET['hash'].'.php');
    $profile = unserialize($str);
    if (is_array($profile) && isset($profile['entry']))

    echo $profile['entry'][0]['name'];
    echo $profile['entry'][0]['preferredUsername']; 
?>
```

My problem is how to figure out how to get the name and last name using this line:

```
echo $profile['entry'][0]['name'];
```

All I get by typing this single line is "Array".

Answer (score 0):

`$profile['entry'][0]['name']` is indeed an array. If you want the formatted name you should access `$profile['entry'][0]['name']['formatted']`